# How to list the file names from a static library with .o extension

Tags: c, build, static-libraries, disassembly, nm

I am having a two c program file `temp1.c` and `temp2.c`. I compiled and generated `dot o` files for this `temp1.o` and `temp2.o`. After that I genrated `final.o` and `final.a` by combining these two `dot o` files. Now these two static libraries are working fine.

Now nm report of `final.a` is displaying all file names and symbols. But nm report of `final.o` is not displaying filenames, its displaying only symbols.

What is the way to get the list of file names which I used for creating `final.o`.

Comment: A library contains objects and an object contains symbols.  If you `ld temp1.o temp2.o -o final.o` you get an object which combines symbols from two objects, but I'm not sure there's any information left about temp1.o and temp2.o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we create `.a` file from `.o` files(`temp1.o` and `temp2.o`) then the `.a` will have the file name of all `.o` files and its content. But while creating `.o` from some `.o` files, then it will contain only content of all `.o` files and the file names of each `.o` will not be present.